# NHibernate Bidirectional Many-to-Many Mapping List / Bag

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm

I am struggling with a bi-directional many-to-many mapping where the order is important on one side, but not the other.

I have two classes: Program and Student.

A program has many students and the sequential order is important.

Program A

1. John
2. Sally
3. Seth

Program B

1. Alex
2. Seth
3. Amy
4. John

A student has many programs, but the order is not important here.

John
* Program A
* Program B

Sally

- Program A

Seth

- Program A
- Program B

Alex

- Program B

Amy

- Program B

So, it appears that I would have a bidirectional many-to-many association between programs and students where I could do things like this...

```
var john = GetJohn();
var programCount = john.Programs.Count; // 2

var programB = GetProgramB();
var studentCount = programB.Students.Count; // 4
var secondStudent = programB.Students[1]; // Seth
```

I cannot figure out how to get the mapping to work. I keep getting PK violation errors.

I have tried the following...

PROGRAM MAPPING

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Program" table="Programs" lazy="false">
        <id name="ID" column="ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Title" column="Title" type="String" length="200" />
        <list name="Students" table="ProgramAssignments" lazy="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="ProgramID" />
            <index column="SequenceIndex" type="Int32" />
            <many-to-many column="StudentID" class="Student" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

STUDENT MAPPING

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
    <class name="Student" table="Students" lazy="false">
        <id name="ID" column="ID" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="Title" column="Title" type="String" length="200" />
        <bag name="Programs" table="ProgramAssignments" lazy="true">
            <key column="StudentID" />
            <many-to-many column="ProgramID" class="Program" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My association table is very simple...

```
ProgramID int
StudentID int
SequenceIndex int
```

The PK is the ProgramID + StudentID.

I really want the association to be managed from the program side because the order of the students in each program is important. But, I really would like to be able to access the programs for a specific student via mystudent.Programs. I have tried many variations of the mapping, including setting inverse=true on the program list, trying different cascade options, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue could be hidden in the fact, that the `<list>` mapping supports multiple assignment of one instance (so there could be student *Seth* assigned twice, with different *SequenceIndex* - violating the PK error)

But I would like to give you a hint. Try to change the approach and introduce the intermediate object. See the NHibernate documentation: [Chapter 24. Best Practices](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/best-practices.html). Quick summary:

> **Don't use exotic association mappings.**
>
> Good usecases for a real `many-to-many` associations are rare. Most of
>   the time you need additional information stored in the "link table".
>   In this case, it is much better to use two one-to-many associations to
>   an intermediate link class. In fact, we think that most associations
>   are one-to-many and many-to-one, you should be careful when using any
>   other association style and ask yourself if it is really neccessary.

And I would say, that this is (could be) the case, because you really need the **Order** ...

Comment: Thanks. This is the approach I ended up using.

Comment: I am sorry, that there wasn't simple answer... But I am sure that this will do what you need at the end. Good luck with NHibernate

Comment: So ... nHibernate doesn't really implement NxM relationships and actually suggest that this kind of relationship is "unusual"? I'm very disappointed with nHibernate and all wrong database modelling practices it suggests. No wonder why serious DBAs are upfront against ORMs...

Comment: @GerardoLima The documentation doesn't suggest that N:M relationships are rare, but rather that they are often best expressed as two one-to-many relationships.

Comment: @gliljas thanks for that comment.. that is exactly true... one-to-many and pairing object with many-to-one is a preferred way...