# Fluent NHibernate HasManyToMany with a discriminator column specifying relationship type

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and I'm trying to map a many-to-many property that simply bypasses the join table. The tricky thing is, the join table has a column that determines what type of relationship it is.

For the purpose of this question, let's say I have a person table and a relation table.

```
PersonTable (PersonId, Name, etc)
RelationTable (RelationType, PersonIdA, PersonIdB)
```

I want to introduce a collection property in Person class for each type of relationship e.g. Sons, Daughters, etc.

```
HasManyToMany<Person>(x => x.Sons)
    .Table("RelationTable")
    .ParentKeyColumn("PersonIdA")
    .ChildKeyColumn("PersonIdB")
    .Where("RelationType='A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_BOY'");

HasManyToMany<Person>(x => x.Daughters)
    .Table("RelationTable")
    .ParentKeyColumn("PersonIdA")
    .ChildKeyColumn("PersonIdB")
    .Where("RelationType='A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_GIRL'");
```

The above mappings are working for reading from the database but not for inserting, for example:

```
Person john = PersonDAO.GetByName("John"); // the Sons and Daughters are loaded fine based on mappings above

john.Sons.Add(new Person("Jack"));  // let's add a new son
PersonDAO.Save(john);               // this fails because RelationType is null
```

Basically when saving Jack as John's new son in the RelationTable I need to have RelationType populated with "A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_BOY", which is not currently happening.
The directive .Where("RelationType='A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_BOY'") is only effective for loading but not for saving.

Any ideas? I think this is somewhat similar to the Discriminator attribute for subclasses.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *Before you'll get your answer, I would suggest avoid the many-to-many if possible. If you like read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136089/1679310) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16827671/1679310)*

Comment: @RadimKöhler, I have read through the links you provided. I actually do have the RelationTable mapped with 2 many-to-one references to Person (as PersonA and PersonB). Using one-to-many (HasMany), how then do you suggest I map Sons and Daughters (both List<Person>) in the Person class taking into account the discriminator values as above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, exactly as you pointed out in your comment:

> I actually do have the RelationTable mapped with 2 **`many-to-one`** references to Person (as PersonA and PersonB). Using **`one-to-many`** (HasMany), how then do you suggest I map Sons and Daughters (both `List<Person>`) in the Person class taking into account the discriminator values as above

So the pairing object in my eyes would be

```
public class PersonRelation
{
    // the pairing table must contain the key column, surrogated ID
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; } // this is a must. 

    public virtual Person Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Child { get; set; }
    public virtual string RelationType { get; set; }
}
```

There MUST be key for this table. Just inject some IDENTITY column with SQL Server.. but have some with surrogated (business domain independent) key.

Here is our Person entity

```
public class Person
{
    IList<PersonRelation> _sons;
    IList<PersonRelation> _daughters;
    ..,
    public virtual IList<PersonRelation> Sons 
    {
        get { return _sons ?? (_sons = new List<PersonRelation>()); }
        set { _sons = value; }
    }
    public virtual IList<PersonRelation> Daughters
    {
        get { return _daughters?? (_daughters= new List<PersonRelation>()); }
        set { _daughters= value; }
    }
}
```

The mapping for Sons *(Daughters would be same)*:

```
HasMany<PersonRelation>(x => x.Sons)
    // .Table("RelationTable") // not needed - part of PersonRleation mapping
    .KeyColumn("PersonIdA")
    .Where("RelationType='A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_BOY'")
    .Inverse()
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan() 
;
```

That would work, if we will always assure, that when adding Son, we also properly set RelationType

```
var parent = ...; // new, loaded
var child  = ...; // new, loaded

var relation = new PersonRelation
{
    Parent = parent;
    Child  = child;
    RelationType = "A_IS_FATHER_OF_B_BOY";
};

parnet.Sons.Add(relation);
```

This must be either part of the Businese layer AddSon() or it could be POCO public method...

NOTE: we can also map reverse end of that relation ... even without relationType filtering:

```
public class Person
{
    ... as above
    public virtual IList<PersonRelation> Parents { get; set; }


HasMany<PersonRelation>(x => x.Parents)
    // instead of this
    // .KeyColumn("PersonIdA")
    // we need this column
    .KeyColumn("PersonIdB")
;
```